# Django: launch a django-independent python script

Tags: python, django

I have a Django + script launch problem. For context: I'm creating a website in Django that uses a database that isn't huge at the moment, but will grow over time.

I've created my own administration according to my needs. A requirement is a retroactive action on the entire database.

In order not to affect the website, the operation is carried out via another python script (which is not in views.py). The script lasts a minute and if I launch it from views.py, the site "freezes" on my side and I can no longer browse. That's why I've decided to create a separate script.

My problem is that I need Django to launch this script without impacting the front-end, i.e. if I click on the script launch button on the front-end, I can continue browsing.

I tried using subprocess :

```
subprocess.run(['python3', '/home/ec2-user/scripts/database_cleaning.py'])
```

Fun fact: the site seems frozen (I've got a spinning wheel on the tab name), but I can navigate and the script seems to work. On the other hand, it sometimes causes bugs when I'm browsing: a psycopg2 transaction doesn't close and the site is "KO'd" until I kill the process directly on PostgreSQL. So it seems that subprocess is not the solution because even if the script outside of Django is launched, it's still linked to Django via subprocess.

Do you know how I can run a python script completely independently of Django, but launch it via a button on the front end? This button performs a back-end action (adding a value to a list then commit the changes to a database), then launches the cleanup script with the new list.

I'm open to any ideas for optimizing this, as long as it doesn't require a full-blown architecture, the script runs on a virtual machine.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use Celery for that: https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/. I might add an answer that illustrates this if I had time.

Comment: Hey thanks, I'll give it a try ! I'll read the documentation this evening. :)

Comment: I know nothing about the `subprocess` command but i have used the `os.system()` command when running backups. E.G. `import os \n os.system("python3 /home/ec2-user/scripts/database_cleaning.py")` Note: If the file you want to run is in the same directory as the file that is running the command, you can just specify the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after searching a little bit more, I found that run may not be a solution, but Popen could work:

`subprocess.Popen(['python3', '/home/ec2-user/scripts/database_cleaning.py'])`

There is now no freeze on the front-end and it doesn't seem to be buggy anymore. But still, if you have any ideas I'll take them :)

If not, i will mark my answer as valid in few days.

I want to try something with Popen now : instead of launching the script with Python, maybe launch a bash script that will launch the Python script.

I figure that if Django launches a source file and it executes correctly, Django will then be "freed", unless it's impacted by a ricochet from the Python script launched by the bash script.